# Couldn't get the 'href' from anchor tag

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Through inspect element on web page, i am able to properly see the link for anchor tag like, [image: Image for that] but when i try to get it through soup, it gives me the result as [image: Image of output (soup)]. I tried lxml and html5lib but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: add your code, and HTML snip, community members won't type code for you to reproduce problem, adding screenshot is bad practice.

Comment: edit the question and add the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, some chunks of the html page that I was scraping were not loaded correctly. I ended up scraping using PhantomJS via Selenium. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287490/is-there-a-way-to-use-phantomjs-in-python). And another [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964760/python-phantomjs-loading-webpage-not-correct).

There's also [dryscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python) , which I've never used, but might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the href by specifying a User-Agent in the headers. Site may be designed to give different response to various browsers. It is better to use a User-Agent similar to the browser which you used to inspect the page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://co.jim-hogg.tx.us/index.php/bids/278-solid-waste-resedential-collection-disposal-bids'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
print(soup.find("div",{"itemprop":"articleBody"}).a['href'])
```

Output

```
http://www.jimhoggcounty.net/files/BIDS/Notice%20for%20bids%20on%20Solid%20Waste%20Residential%20%26%20CommercialCollection.pdf
```

Note:
My region was blocked by the site, so i had to use a proxy to get a response. I have removed that additional code.